# Inserted code producing unexpected result

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

So eventually I want to have a greasemonkey script but for now I have only been working with firebug to test out my html/javascript.

I have this code to insert one button in the HTML toolbar for blogger.
The button is supposed to replace all the `&nbsp;` with " " as blogger seems to just randomly add `&nbsp;` into my blogs posts and can cause the published article to look weird (a bunch of words separated in between with `&nbsp;`s will not want to break in the middle unlike the same words separated with " ").

```
 document.getElementById("postingHtmlToolbar").firstChild.innerHTML += '<div id="SP" class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button" title="SP" role="button" style="-moz-user-select: none;"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-outer-box"><div class="goog-inline-block goog-toolbar-button-inner-box"><a href="javascript:document.getElementById(\'postingHtmlBox\').value = document.getElementById(\'postingHtmlBox\').value.replace(/&nbsp;/g, \' \');"><b>SP</b></a></div></div></div>';
```

Which trimming away the formatting just leaves us with.

```
  <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox').value = document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox').value.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');"><b>SP</b></a>
```

The funny thing is that that same code (minus the href, javascript: stuff) run from firebug works perfectly.

But when it is inserted like this and run it blanks the entire web page and writes the value of `document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox').value.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ')` into this black page.

Am I forgetting something stupid? Is this supposed to happen? Do I have some stupid syntax error? What would you suggest as a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put JS code in `href`. use `onclick`:

```
<a href="javascript//" onclick="document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox').value = document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox').value.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');"><b>SP</b></a>
```

Comment: It did not like the javascript// (it thought it was a address) So I replaced it with a JS:void(0); and firebug shows: `<a onclick="document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox').value = document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox').value.replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');" href="javascript:void(0);"><b>SP</b></a>`

But it no longer seems to be running the code, nothing happens when I click it at least (no change, no errors.)

Comment: I think it was working but another error cropped up at the same time, firebug or some other layer turned the `&nbsp;` into a " " in the regex.
Browsers/websites really have to start making up their minds, are these two things equivalent or not because this halfway thing where sometimes they are and other times they are not is really screwy.

Comment: So just for the record the regex turned out to be: `/&amp;nbsp;/g`
But i am not sure if this is a firebug specific issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `void(0);` to the end of the href.

Basically, the output of the last statement (if any) is replacing the document (i've had the same problem), so making the last statement one with no output will avoid the problem

Comment: I added it in, getting a href looking like `javascript:document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox').value%20=%20document.getElementById('postingHtmlBox').value.replace(/%C2%A0/g,%20'%20');void(0);`
But that seemed to prevent me from activating the button at all, now when I click it nothing happens (no errors, no changes).

Comment: Are the characters URL encoded like that? If so, try replacing the %xx with the original characters

Comment: No Firebug copy seems to be adding them, I am imputing normal characters and firebug shows normal characters when I look at them
(note: will be away from the computer for the next little bit, so the instant responses will stop)